# Ordinal column position from sys schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I get the following query, working on both views and tables, by using the SYS schema?

```
SELECT c.column_name,c.ordinal_position
from information_schema.columns c
where TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' 
and table_name='def_transaction_pt'
```

I have used the following until now, but I don't know where to get the ordinal column position from:

```
select *
from 
    sys.objects o
    inner join sys.columns c on o.object_id=c.object_id
where o.name='def_transaction_pt'
```

Comment: Simply curiosity: was there a specific requirement to use `sys.columns` instead of `information_schema.columns`? I ran an execution plan comparison between your original using `information_schema.columns` vs. the accepted answer using `sys.columns` joined to `sys.objects` and I get performance improvements using latter: 39% for sys.columns vs. 61% when using `information_schema.columns`. Was this what you what you were looking for or was there another reason for moving to sys.columns?

Comment: @JeffMergler No idea why George is moving away from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` but I am becouse of performance. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is slower and slower the more tables there are in the database. At ~1.8k tables (more then half of them created by bug :) s**t happens :) ) simple query to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` take seconds (on prod ssd - on dev hdd it is much worse, querying "get all tables" from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` take ~40s but more or less the same query from `sys.tables inner join sys.schemas` is almost instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path...

```
DECLARE @ObjectName sysname = 'def_transaction_pt',
        @SchemaName sysname = 'dbo'

SELECT c.name As Column_Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.column_id) As Ordinal_Position
FROM sys.columns AS c
JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON c.object_id = o.object_id 
JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE o.name = @ObjectName
AND s.name = @SchemaName
```

Note: I've only joined the `sys.schemas` to enable filtering using schema name,
and `sys.objects` to allow filtering using table/view name

After reading the comments and documentation, I've decided to adopt Larnu's suggestion about using row_number instead of the column_id directly.
Also, I've changed `All_columns` to `Columns` since it contains the columns from both tables and views.

BTW, the official documentation of [`information_schema.Columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) describes the `Ordinal_Position` as "Column identification number." - which might be just the same as the `Column_Id` - It would require more testing to figure out that part.

BTW #2: Though you can't change the column's ordinal position using an alter table, it is possible to do using the visual designer (which in turn, drops and re-creates the table) - and if you do that, the column id for all columns is re-calculated, so it's always corresponding with the actual ordinal position (gaps aside).

Comment: The documentation for sys.columns.column_id states: "ID of the column. Is unique within the object. Column IDs might not be sequential." Is this really the ordinal position?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Yes, however, if you alter the table and `DROP ` column, it won't be any more. Zohar is almost there as well. I suggest adding `ROW_NUMBER` here. Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=98cbfba104afd094f370eaf065a266a3)

Comment: Actually, I didn't check the documentation, I've just took the column that had the same values as the `ordinal_position` when tested... give me a minute or two to try and find a proper documentation

Comment: (I should probably be a little more specific). The id of the column will always be incremental. In SQL Server you can't add a column at position, so a newest column will always have the highest value `column_id`, and when a table is initially created, the value they are assigned for `column_id` is effectively their ordinal position. AS a further example, note that the `column_id` 3 and 4 are not reused here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2ddb7ec13defdc7daaa284d73851e7be)

Comment: Ah, OK, that suits me well. Thank you everyone.